# mosaic dataset and overview failed in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, mosaic-dataset

I m working with arcgis 10.
i m trying to optimize the storage and the visualization of heavy raster.
After importing raster in file geodatabase i put them in a mosaic dataset and i generate overview but:

1. Some raster are missing, and some are cut.
2. Overview are shifted

However i m sure that my input raster are in good projection, with stastistics calculated and pyramids.
Any help?

Comment: Please describe the precise steps that you performed, with lots of detail, so that a potential answerer might be able follow or test what you are asking.